# Backbone Marionette - Router & Controller

Tags: marionette

Let say if my apps have 2 models and 2 collections

1. Author (Model) | AuthorList (Collection)
2. Book   (Model) | BookList   (Collection)

Should I create a router and controller for Author
and create another router and controller for Book ?

or should I just create only 1 router and controller for both Author and Book?

```
//Router for Author
appRoutes {
   "authors/:id":"showAuthor"
   "authors": "showAuthorList"
   ...
}


//Router for Book
appRoutes {
   "books/:id":"showBook"
   "books": "showBookList"
   ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the answer is: "it depends". Both will work, and the solution you choose will come down to preference.

However, for larger scale applications, it makes a lot of sense to have separate routing controllers (and to sub-divide the app into smaller bits). You can see an example of the multiple routers in [the code](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction) accompanying my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction).

Comment: Thanks~ I think your example code will give me some idea about this.